# Rest with Curl does not return anything

Tags: php, rest

This is the code. 
I am using a rest api to and http authentication to authenticate the user.
On running the function, nothing is getting displayed.
I am not getting a success/error from the response. The response is blank and there is no error as well. Please help

```
<?php
$method = "POST";
$url = "https://www.myproject.com/api/v1/projects/create";
$data_array = array("projectName"=>"Project1");
$data = json_encode($data_array);
$response = CallAPI($method,$url,$data);

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    //base64
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "anemail@gmail.com:arpit.1995");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;

}
$response = CallAPI($method,$url,$data);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Try get errors using this:
`$curlErr = curl_error($ch);`
And HTTPCODE using this :
`$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

Comment: It showed this error:

Comment: Undefined variable: ch and curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null

Comment: You have to query your api with CURLOPT_POSTFIELD as json, but it has to be something like `foo=bar&test=123..and so on` ... and in case of PUT-request your data doesn't assigned anywhere. Is your REST-api returns valid answer if you call this via JS or POST-form ?

Comment: replace `$ch` with `$curl`